# Compatibility porting program

Tags: dmx512

I am interested in trying to get a program ported to 64-bit and would like to know if it's even a good candidate for porting.  I am a lighting director and have built a SUSE 11.1 Linux box for a program called [MagicQ](http://www.chamsys.co.uk/products) made by Chamsys (http://www.chamsys.be/download.html). I have been working on this for about 6 months now and have all hardware recognised. I am still working on stage visualizers, and I have a separate CPU/board generating the [DMX512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512) code via [PoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet). I don't think getting it to run in SUSE will be a problem "it was natively built for Ubuntu".

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Unbuntu and Suse are subtlely different in how things are laid out for file sytems, home directories and such. Usually when you try to install a package on either on you need to use their own package manager programs so that all dependincies are handled and you don't need to manually try to find package 'x' version 'y' and package 'a' version 'b' just to get something working.

If you know that you have all the dependencies covered, and if you have the raw source code, you should be able to just run a compilier against the source code and have it compilied for a 64-bit processor.

Here is a link to the [GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for your reference.

Good luck with your porting project.